# Return a path and a particular node type from the path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I say I have the following graph

```
(:A) -> (:B {name:'B-1'}) -> (:C) -> (:D)
     -> (:X) -> (:B {name:'B-2'} -> (:Z)
```

Now A, B, C, etc are node types with different node attributes. i.e., the two B nodes have a name attribute with different values to differentiate the two. Say now I want to find out the path between A to Z, I can do

```
MATCH p1 = ((:A)-[*]-(:Z))
return p1
```

But I also want to return the two B nodes using the same query or is there a way to post processing p1 to extract the two B nodes in neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the RETURN as follows:

```
RETURN p1,
       [ n IN nodes(p1) WHERE n:B] AS arrayWithBNodes
```

or if you just want the names:

```
RETURN p1,
       [ n IN nodes(p1) WHERE n:B | n.name] AS arrayWithNamesOfBNodes
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it helpful to propagate properties into downstream nodes or add new relationship? The "post processing" as you call it can involve redundancies which have a cost (extra storage/memory) but the accelerated traversals can justify that cost. The acceleration comes from either shortening the traversal because either 1) there is a new relationship or 2) because you start the traversal at a downstream point. Is there a property in (:A) which you can place in (:Z) or other intermediary node? Is a relationship between A and Z sensible? The one-time effort to do enhancements across the entire graph will then make each individual query very fast. You can also use this strategy to manage provenance; it's complicated to keep track of how A and Z are related now.